# Как исправить баг с play pause HTML5 в google chrome?

Tags: javascript, html5, web-audio

При разработке радиоприёмника столкнулся с проблемой в google chrome. Именно в chrome, что самое поразительное, в остальных браузерах всё работает прекрасно. В chrome происходят 2 неведомых бага. Один явный, другой непонятно откуда взявшийся и даже нагуглить его не выходит. 
Сначала про [приёмник](http://radiotune.concord-media.ru):

В нём есть переключалки станций - всего их около 20. Работает он на плагине buzz.js (сначала хотел сделать нативно через `audio src`, но потом начал копаться на stackoverflow и нашёл его, когда обнаружил в хроме первый баг с кэшированием звука).

- Баг №1: Он явный и загуглить его можно было. В консоль выпадала
  ошибка, а проигрывание прекращалось.

  > Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().

  Я нашёл багрепорт. Что странно - он закрыт, но судя по всему
  в официальном обновлении фикс не выкатили, ибо хром я обновлял пару
  недель назад, а ветка закрыта уже как с 8 месяцев. На форумах
  предлагают костыли, типа `setTimeout`. Не знаю как остальные ставили на
  это галки - лично мне не помогло. Скорее всего потому что в `src` у
  меня потоковые ссылки и с ними всё не так просто. Сталкивался ли
  кто-то с этим багом на практике? Как боролись?
- Баг №2: Выше уже упоминал. Chrome кэширует проигранный звук.
  Как результат, после перемотки на ту же станцию он начинает
  проигрывать то, что уже закэшировал при первом воспроизведении. Как
  отключить это я так и не понял. Когда пробовал делать нативными
  методами (до установки buzz.js) я удалял в алгоритме переключения
  `src`, потом возвращал обратно, на `audio` повесил `preload none`, пробовал
  `current time` на ноль скидывать и не скидывать. Ничего не помогает.

Comment: Перед заявлением о баге, нужно убедится что это действительно баг, а не [tag:так-задумано].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не баг браузера. Поведение браузера весьма логично. Звуковой поток для браузера — это прежде всего файл (mp3, ogg… или что у вас там).

Чтобы браузер не кешировал поток при остановке, переключении (т.е. физической смене `src` нужно браузеру отдавать правильные заголовки на сервере.

Если это реализовать невозможно по каким-либо причинам, можно браузер обмануть. Тогда в конце пути к потоку нужно добавлять случайный параметр, например, в виде случайного числа. То есть путь к потоку будет выглядеть как `src="path_to_stream.mp3?76876343087987"`

Для браузера это будет всегда разный файл, и, соответственно, каждый раз будет кешироваться разный.

Answer (score -1):

Баг №1: у тэга video выставить `muted="muted"`, а в js'ке уже по `on('playing'. function(){$('video')get(0).muted = false;});`